# Which spells trigger the second benefit of Shield Master?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats

The Shield Master feat includes the following benefit:

> lf you aren't incapacitated, you can add your shield's AC
>   bonus to any Dexterity saving throw you make against
>   a spell or other harmful effect **that targets only you**.

This *sounds* great, until you [realise that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97513/15469) spells like *Fireball* (the vast majority of spells that trigger a Dexterity saving throw) target a point, not a creature.

> For a spell like fireball, the target is the point in space where the ball of fire erupts.

So what spells are there (WotC published 5e material only) that target a single creature and require that creature to make a Dexterity saving throw?

Comment: The benefit should also help versus trap effects with dex saving throws.

Comment: @NeilSlater Yep, but those are much harder to find, since they're mostly scattered through adventures.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The spells from the Player's Handbook that target a single creature and trigger a Dexterity saving throw are:

- *Acid Splash*, as long as the caster doesn't choose to target 2 creatures.
- *Chain Lightning*, if there are no other targets within 30 feet of you.
- *Disintegrate*
- *Hellish Rebuke*
- *Otiluke's Resilient Sphere*
- *Sacred Flame*

And from the Elemental Evil Player's Companion:

- *Immolation*

None of the new spells from the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide meet the required conditions.

Comment: If you are the sole target of a lightning bolt, that ought to meet the criteria

Comment: PHB, page 202: For a spell like *fireball*, the target is the point in space where the ball of fire erupts.

Comment: AoE spells unfortunately don't qualify.

Comment: For an alternative and more broadly applicable reference, there's also PHB page 204: A spell's description tells you whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or a point of origin for an area of effect

Comment: I was going to list the Battle Master maneuvers that triggered Dexterity saves as well ... and there aren't any!

Comment: I think the bonus action ramming effect of a Flaming Sphere would qualify, but not the proximity burn effect.

Comment: This seems like a really easy feat to houserule... What a limitation.  Definitely not as good as other options by RaW.